# Styling a combobox's PART_EditableTextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, styling

I want to add conditionnal formatting (just font color) to the textbox part of a combobox. According to MSDN, it's the "PART_EditableTextBox" element. A quick search on SO got me started but I now face a problem: it overrides the whole template. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12011848/1991423), I can use "BasedOn" to override only specific properties but I've no idea how/where to use it.
This is my current template:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="ComboBox" <!--Here?--> >
        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" <!--Maybe Here?-->>
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="MAL">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrange"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

It works, I can still type in valid values and "MAL" does make the text orange but there's no dropdown anymore.
On MSDN, I found the following:

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
               Style="{x:Null}"
               Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Margin="3,3,23,3"
               Focusable="True"
               Background="Transparent"
               Visibility="Hidden"
               IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
```

I suppose I should base my template on this "ComboBoxTextBox" but I don't know how to reference it. Do I really need to copy the whole template or is there a way to override a specific property?

EDIT:
On the same MSDN page comboboxTextBox is defined as

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox"
                 TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
       <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
          Focusable="False"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

I don't see how overriding this template removes the dropdown list.

Comment: It seems to me that what your ControlTemplate is doing is basically re-templating your ComboxBox to only have a TextBox. If you want to see the dropdown list, you need to have a control definition for that PART! Unfortunately I'm not good enough at ReTemplating to help you with this, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got really confused after reading all of your code and having a really looooooong day at work, I totally missed the point of your question.... which is

**I want to add conditionnal formatting (just font color) to the textbox part of a combobox**

Well if that's all you want to do, then it's really easy with just a simple style trigger.
I can achieve that with this xaml.

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="MAL">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrange" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBoxItem>MAL</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this way first but it also changes the foreground color of the whole dropdown list.