# ControlTemplate wpf

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

How can I add **polygon to ControlTemplate** and `ControlTemplate to button`
How can i do this but in code :

```
<Button x:Name="btnNew" Content="click me" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Height="250" BorderThickness="0" UseLayoutRounding="True" >


        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Polygon x:Name="poly" Points="0,50 200,20 230,150 20,200">
                    <Polygon.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush x:Name="imgtem" Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/67.png">
                        </ImageBrush>
                    </Polygon.Fill>
                </Polygon>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define a WPF ControlTemplate at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732736/define-a-wpf-controltemplate-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `XamlReader.Parse` to create the `ControlTemplate` and then simply set the properties of the `Button`:

```
string xaml = "<ControlTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\"><Polygon x:Name=\"poly\" Points=\"0,50 200,20 230,150 20,200\"><Polygon.Fill><ImageBrush x:Name=\"imgtem\" Stretch=\"Fill\" ImageSource=\"Images/67.png\"></ImageBrush></Polygon.Fill></Polygon></ControlTemplate>";
ControlTemplate template = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as ControlTemplate;

Button button = new Button();
button.Name = "btnNew";
button.Content = "Click me";
button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
button.Margin = new Thickness(54, 10, 0, 0);
//...
button.Template = template;
```